# Authorization of UI Elements in .NET WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, authorization, aop

I have a general question about the best approach for authorizing UI elements for application Roles. What I mean is an Administrator can see buttons, menu items, etc, that a regular User cannot see. What is the best practice for this?

I realize that there could be multiple screens based on Role (an Admin screen, the same screen duplicated for User, etc), that definitely seems like overkill. I also want to keep Separation of Concern so my authorization code is not intermingled with display functionality. In other words, I want to avoid:

```
if( current_user.IsInRole("administrator") )
  button.Enabled = true;
```

I have been looking at Aspects with PostSharp, which seems *almost* exactly what I want to do, but it doesn't seem to logically extend to the UI.

I'm sure I'm missing something, what is it?

Thanks -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems likely that your code will eventually compile a list of UI elements to hide, or perform a given action to, and then perform those actions based on the current role. Something like

```
Dictionary<Control, Action<Control, string>> actions = new Dictionary<Control, Action<Control, string>>
{
    { button, (c, r) => c.Enabled = (r == "administrator") },
    // etc.
};
```

How you compile that list is primarily what your question is concerned with. AOP frameworks definitely help with the separation of concerns, but a homebrew solution wouldn't be impossible. I'm thinking something like:

- Create an `EnableForRoleAttribute`, with parameter `role`.
- Reflect on your forms (possibly using reflection to find the forms, or possibly providing them to your code directly, or even finding forms decorated with a `RoleVaryingAttribute` of your creation).
- Reflect on the fields of your forms, filtering for `Control` instances, then for `Control` instances with the `EnableForRoleAttribute`.
- Now you have your list! Set `Enabled` based on the role.

The above bulleted list is specific to your `Enabled` example, mainly because attributes can't take lambdas as parameters :(. You could be more flexible with a `SetPropertyIfInRoleAttribute` with parameters `role`, `propertyName`, and `propertyValue`. Or any such construction.

Basically, the AOP frameworks make this work easier for you, and some like PostSharp make it happen at compilation time instead of runtime. But the homebrew solution is pretty valid too.

Comment: Domenic - thanks, the SetPropertyIfInRoleAttribute (or SetPropertyByRoleAttribute) seems like a nice middle ground, and as of this moment I am leaning that way. Great explanation, thanks for clarifying. Now I see, lambda in an Attribute constructor would be very useful!

Comment: As a follow up, what I ran into using PostSharp was that I could not get the custom attribute because I am decorating .NET framework classes (textboxes, etc) at an instance level. I think I'll run into the same issue again. Although you provided a great answer to the original question, one answer often leads to two more questions... =D